# Registry start main VS progect file .exe instead of my request

Tags: c#, registry, startup

I made a software with VS. This software has 1 Solution and 2 Projects.

1. APM (Main Form)
2. APM Background (Sort of service)

The Startup project for VS is "APM". After i built the solution i made it to start on windows startup by writing this code in APM.

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
reg.SetValue("AutoPostMail", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).ToString() + @"\APM Background.exe);//calling APM Background
```

My registry saved it
KEY `AutoPostMail`
VALUE `C:\Users\oskar ersly\Desktop\APM\AutoPostMail\APM Background.exe`

But for some reason on windows startup is starting APM.exe and if i start manually APM Background.exe all work fine. What i'm missing ? Any idea?

Comment: If i type "msconfig" in the startup panel i have startup item as APM but the same Command is `C:\Users\oskar ersly\Desktop\APM\AutoPostMail\APM Background.exe` ...

Comment: Is this your real code? it has a syntax error which always makes me suspicious

Comment: Yes it is, can you tell which syntax error i did ?

Comment: You forgot a `"`, obviously not the issue, but it is always suspicious

Comment: hahah, maybe i need to sleep more at the nights. Obiously i didn't made this error on my real project. Thank you anyway. The real problem was the Assenbly name of the project, VS allow you to use spaces in the name but from what i see is better to not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the name of second project from "APM Background" to "apmbg".